# How to do object.getClass().getName() in Java

Tags: java

I want to implement to classes, `Food` and `FoodFactory` such that they satisfies the following input and output.

```
//Input:
FoodFactory ff = new FoodFactory();
Food f1 = ff.getFood('Fruit');
Food f2 = ff.getFood('Meat');
f1.serveFood(); 
f2.serveFood();
System.out.println(f1.getClass().getSuperClass().getName());
System.out.println(f1.getClass().getName());
System.out.println(f2.getClass().getName());

//Output:
I'm serving Fruit
I'm serving Meat
Food
Fruit
Meat
```

Suppose we have the following constraints:

1. Only write the two classes `Food` and `FoodFactory`
2. Only java.util.* is allowed

What I don't know is how to make `getClass().getName()` working in different situation. I can only get `FoodFactory`.

Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried so far in your implementation of the classes? this is a pretty straight forward problem and smells of homework help

Comment: If anyone can point out some reference, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: An official tutorial is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are practicing some OO with Java . It's better if you ask a doubt instead the full scenario.

However I will paste a sample here and you can ask any doubt you have.
FoodFactory class below, note that for a name you will get the right Object.

```
public class FoodFactory {

  public Food getFood(String food) {

    if ("Meat".equals(food)) {
      return new Meat();
    } else if ("Fruit".equals(food)) {
      return new Fruit();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No food found with name " + food);
  }
}
```

Both your Food classes should be created, in this case Meat and Fruit.

```
public class Meat extends Food {
}
```

Your Food will print message based on current classes. Others will inherit the behavior.

```
public class Food {
  public void serveFood() {
    System.out.println("I'm serving " + getClass().getSimpleName());
  }
}
```

Then you can simply run your scenario and note that getClass will run for right hierarchy.

```
FoodFactory ff = new FoodFactory();
Food f1 = ff.getFood("Fruit");
Food f2 = ff.getFood("Meat");
f1.serveFood();
f2.serveFood();
System.out.println(f1.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println(f1.getClass().getSimpleName());
System.out.println(f2.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

Try to play with it and understand.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your idea the last two lines of the output is good. But the `System.out.println(f1.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName());
`

Comment: I got an error:FoodFactory.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(f1.getClass().getSuperClass().getSimpleName());
                                    ^
  symbol:   method getSuperClass()
  location: class Class<CAP#1>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Food from capture of ? extends Food
1 error

Comment: Now I know, it should be getSuperclass() :)